# Copyright of screens/movie posters

Tags: publishing, copyright

I am writing a (commercial) book about cinema and reviews of movies. My question is about the pictures to illustrate the text.

For example I suppose that I can't use the promotional poster of a movie without paying for it.

Then what about a simple screen of the movie? Do I need the authorization?

At least can I use (for free) a portrait of the director of the movie?

Note: This is an author edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just written a book and that same issue, needing lots of images from films to illustrate it. I'm going to assume that its some kind of 'educational' work in that its purpose is to teach people something, and in that case, according to my publisher it's okay to go ahead and use posters, promotional materials and screengrabs if the films are reasonably old (say 2 or 3 years) because they can claim fair use under a provision for education that all publishers lean on when they sell these types of books.

I was dubious at first but they've been in a business a long time and the reality is that if this wasn't the case then no educational books would ever be published with images because the returns could never justify the probable costs of paying for them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1! In a former life I specialised in this (exceptions to copyright) at university. The law is insanely complicated - I wrote a year-long dissertation on it and still wouldn't consider myself anything like an expert. It also varies in important ways between different jurisdictions (e.g. between the US and Europe). The good news is that your publisher will likely be able to handle it for you, assuming they're experienced in this type of publishing.

Comment: If you're self-publishing, you'll have to either accept the risk that you encounter a copyright headache if/when your book reaches prominence, or budget to get tailored advice from a lawyer who specialises in intellectual property. 

The second option will be extensive, but you can also get a good start by googling around (try 'copyright exceptions + [your country]').